# Can't load GLSL Shader file using JavaScript into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, glsl

So I have this HTML object:

```
    <div class="animation" onclick="javascript:loadGlslAnimation(this, 'some_url_containing_my_shader.com')" id="a1">
    </div>
```

And this JavaScript function, using an `XMLHttpRequest` to dynamically insert my shader file into the webpage:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

function loadGlslAnimation(element,url) {
    request.open("GET", url);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && request.status === 200) {
            var data = request.responseText;
            console.log('-->' + url + 'data:' + data);
            var scr = '<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">'+data+'</script>';
            element.innerHTML = scr;
        }
    }
    request.send();
}
```

It seems the above is working in inserting the GLSL as a script into my div-animation object:
[image: image showing GLSL script is correctly inserted into HTML object]

However, the animation doesn't display on the webpage.

Is it an issue where the script needs to be reloaded?

Or am I missing something (i.e. a .vert file [I don't know what it is] in addition to my .frag file)?

Here is the CSS describing my div-animation object, for reference:

```
.animation{
    height: 400px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Are you just inserting the `<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">` into the document and expecting something to visually happen? You'll need to use [WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API) to create a shader and render something using that shader.

Comment: When you see people using `<script>` tags for shaders, it is just a convenient way to store a string of code in an HTML page. It does nothing by itself.